# IE8 Jquery scrollTop always returns 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I wrote a small plugin for jQuery for a simple parallax scrolling effect. It's working in all browsers except for < ie8.

```
$.fn.extend({ 
    //plugin name - parallax ( simpel )
    parallax: function(options) {

        var defaults = {
            speed: 3
        };

        var options = $.extend(defaults, options);
        var o = options;
        var obj = $(this);
        var s = $(window).scrollTop() / o.speed;

        if ($.browser.msie && parseInt($.browser.version, 10) <= 8) {
            obj.css({"top" : -s + "px"});
        }else{
            obj.css("-webkit-transform", "translateY(-" + s + "px)");
            obj.css("-moz-transform", "translateY(-" + s + "px)");
            obj.css("-ms-transform", "translateY(-" + s + "px)");
        }                                
    }
});
```

In my main jQuery file i'm using the code like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    $('.headMenu').parallax({speed: 6});
    $('.header_img').parallax();
});
```

For some reason 's' Always stays 0. Can't find why. I think the $(window).scroll is not working in IE8.

Answer (score -2):

I have had bad luck with scrollTop() in IE in the past, not sure why, though. If it fits your needs, try using `window.scrollTo(0, 0);` worked for me always, in all IEs :-)

Comment: scrollTo is not the same as scrollTop? I need to get the position of how far someone has scrolled and update this value when someone scrolls. In this case variable 's'.

Comment: I know, that's why I said "if it fits your need" :-)